# How can I sort a 2-D array in MATLAB with respect to one column?

Tags: matlab, sorting, matrix, octave

I would like to sort a matrix according to a particular column. There is a `sort` function, but it sorts all columns independently.

For example, if my matrix `data` is:

```
 1     3
 5     7
-1     4
```

Then the desired output (sorting by the first column) would be:

```
-1     4
 1     3
 5     7
```

But the output of `sort(data)` is:

```
-1     3
 1     4
 5     7
```

How can I sort this matrix by the first column?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

I think the [sortrows](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html) function is what you're looking for.

```
>> sortrows(data,1)

ans =

    -1     4
     1     3
     5     7
```

Comment: thanks. i wonder why i overlooked it in the "see also" for sort

Answer (score 6):

An alternative to `sortrows()`, which can be applied to broader scenarios.

1. save the sorting indices of the row/column you want to order by:

   ```
   [~,idx]=sort(data(:,1));
   ```
2. reorder all the rows/columns according to the previous sorted indices

   ```
   data=data(idx,:)
   ```