# How would I do a nested sort in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, sorting, matrix, nested

I am looking to do a nested sort with a matrix in MATLAB. Say my matrix looks like this:

```
[b a; 
 b c;
 a c;
 a a]
```

I would like to first sort by the first column and maintain that sort, then sort by the second column. The result would be:

```
[a a;
 a c;
 b a;
 b c]
```

How would it be done?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134712/sorting-2-d-array-in-matlab-w-r-t-one-column

Answer (score 13):

[sortrows](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/index.html?/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/sortrows.html) would do the trick.

To be more detailed, sortrows(A,[1 2]), where A is your matrix.

Comment: Thank you very much. That usage is not in the doc. Pretty intuitive when I think about it.