# How do I maintain rows when sorting a matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, sorting, matrix

I have a 2-by-3 matrix, and I want to sort it according to the first column. Here's an example:

```
data   will change to -->  new data
11 33                      10 22
22 44                      11 33 
10 22                      22 44
```

I have this code for sorting a matrix `A` but it doesn't work well:

```
sort(A,1,'ascend');
```

Comment: Although it doesn't show up on the Related sidebar, I found a *very* old duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134712/sorting-2-d-array-in-matlab-w-r-t-one-column . I'm going to try and retag these two so they are more likely to show up in searches.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [SORTROWS](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/sortrows.html) function can handle that for you:

```
B = sortrows(A);
```

Comment: How can I save the sorted data back to the same txt file?

Comment: @Jessy: To write the sorted data back to a file, you can use FPRINTF (http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/fprintf.html). Here's an example: `fid = fopen('newdata1.txt','w'); fprintf(fid,'%f %f\n',B.'); fclose(fid);`

Comment: gnovice@ thanks..I have problem, it doesnt printed in the txt file as excatly shown in the output of B=sortrows(A)

Comment: @Jessy: Two possible solutions: 1) Make sure you are transposing `B` with `.'` before writing it out. 2) You may have to have `\r\n` instead of `\n` in the format string for FPRINTF.

Answer (score 3):

As @gnovice suggests, [`sortrows`](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/sortrows.html) is the best solution here. You can also specify more than one output for the [`sort`](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/sort.html) and [`sortrows`](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/sortrows.html)commands, which will return the sort index. You can use this to modify your other columns as well or just to keep track of the permutation. For example:

```
A=rand(10,2);
[B, idx]=sortrows(A);
```