# Sorting multiple arrays based on another arrays sorted order

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting, multidimensional-array, octave

I have three separate arrays in matlab/octave and they are all associated with each other.

I'm trying to sort the array values of a and b based on the sort of c (so when c is sorted, a and b arrays are sorted in the same order as the c array).

```
Example:
Original Array
a= [1.2   2   3   4    5   6]
b= [3     5   6   4.1  7   9]
c= [2.2   1   9   6    8   3]
```

**Arrays a and b are based on the sort of c 
(notice all the arrays are sorted based on the order Array c is sorted in)**

```
Final Array that I want:
a= [2   1.2   6   4    5   3]
b= [5   3     9   4.1  7   6]
c= [1   2.2   3   6    8   9]
```

Aloha
Rick

PS: I'm using matlab/octave if there is a better way to do this please let me know

Comment: possible duplicate of [MATLAB - Sort a matrix based off how a vector is sorted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13998098/matlab-sort-a-matrix-based-off-how-a-vector-is-sorted) ... and this answer is also a duplicate. These question already appeared a bunch of time, just search for "vector" instead of "array"

Comment: short answer: get the sorting indexes from `sort` and [apply them to the other arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2679517/2778484) OR put the vectors as columns of a matrix and [use `sortrows`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/135115/2778484)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
[sorted, indices] = sort(c)
% get your output with
a(indices)
b(indices)
```